# Maximum number of records in a Firebird database table same as mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, limit, firebird

I've been using mysql database to database management system but I found errors with mysql when it reached six hundred thousand records in the table. whether it will be the same happens when I use firebird database? whether the storage limit in firebird database with mysql if I use the same hard drive capacity?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that MySQL would generate errors with only 600,000 records. That is nothing to a database.

Comment: I think so but i don't know why, I adding 2000 records per day. how many i can adding records normally?

Comment: I would suggest posting a separate question describing the problems and errors you get with MySQL. Those 2000 records per day are peanuts. There are systems that process that number per second (on MySQL).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Size of Firebird database is unlimited (limited by filesystem). In one table you can store ~32TB of data. Number of rows is 16 billion (confirmed), but probably more (this number is not hard limit).

Comment: See also http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-technical-specifications/ (even though it is from 2007 I think it is still up-to-date for Firebird 2.5)